# Get port value as output of security group in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-security-group, terraform-aws-modules

I have the code to create security group in terraform

```
resource "aws_security_group" "eks_group1"{
description = "Valid security group"
name = "eks_group1"

  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port = 443
    protocol = "tcp"
  }
}
```

I am trying to output the port value mentioned in "to_port"

```
output "allowed_ports" {
    value = aws_security_group.eks_group1.ingress
}
```

Generated output

```
allowed_ports = toset([
{
    "cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
    "description" = ""
    "from_port" = 443
    "ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
    "prefix_list_ids" = tolist([])
    "protocol" = "tcp"
    "security_groups" = toset([])
    "self" = false
    "to_port" = 443
  },
])
```

I tried aws_security_group.eks_group1.ingress[0], tomap, lookup functions to access values but no luck.
Any way to access value of "to_port" in output?

My end goal is to check port 443 is used in security group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allowed_blocks` output value includes `toset([...])` in its output, which suggests that the provider has declared `ingress` as being represented as a *set of objects* data type.

Sets do not have any particular order, so it's not meaningful to ask for "the first element" of a set. However, since your example has only one `ingress` block it *is* meaningful to ask for "the *only* element of the set". You can do that concisely using [the `one` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/one):

```
output "allowed_port" {
  value = one(aws_security_group.eks_group1.ingress).to_port
}
```

Your output value would then be the following:

```
allowed_port = 443
```

The above will fail with an error if there isn't exactly one `ingress` block. If you actually need to support any number of ingress blocks, you can instead construct a set of numbers representing the port numbers, like this:

```
output "allowed_ports" {
  value = toset(aws_security_group.eks_group1.ingress[*].to_port)
}
```

The above uses [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) to derive a collection of port numbers from the collection of objects representing the `ingress` blocks. Then `toset` converts that result to also be a set, which preserves the inherent un-ordered-ness of these port numbers.

Your output value would then be the following:

```
allowed_ports = toset([
  443,
])
```